# TestNG: Run only one method/class "singlethreaded"*

Tags: multithreading, testng

I have to test one class for it's output to System.out. To do so I redirect System.out to my OutputStream, let my method output it's stuff and check what my stream has recorded. Afterwards i restore System.out.**

All fine until there are other threads which are run in parallel and write to stdout. So things get mixed up and my tests fail.

Is there a method (preferably via annotations) to tell TestNG to run this test-class/-method without running another test in parallel while keeping the other classes running parallel?

Thanks a lot

---

*) "singlethreaded" is not the right word here but I don't know a better one to put it in headlines.

**) I know that this is a bit hacky but I can't inject a stream to this class for reasons so ancient only the balrog knows.